# Nexus3 npm repository shows bug icon in the front of dependency and could not packaging project

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-sass, nexus3

Nexus3 npm repository shows bug icon in the front of dependency. But most dependencies show normal icon.
The dependency was uploaded manually. When I run command: `npm run build`, it print errors:

````
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\build\build.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:24:22)
    at D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:286:20
    at D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at Object.context.callback (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at selectBlock (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\select.js:25:19)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\project\minda-opinion-main-ui\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js:75:12)
 @ ./src/components/Breadcrumb/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=1d619bfe&rel=stylesheet%2Fscss&lang=scss&scoped=true& 1:0-476 1:492-495 1:497-970 1:497-970
 @ ./src/components/Breadcrumb/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?cacheDirectory!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/layout/components/User/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/layout/components/User/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/layout/components/User/index.vue
 @ ./src/views lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object
 @ ./src/store/modules/permission.js
 @ ./src/permission.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/main.js```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Appreciation for your help!
````

Comment: `node-sass` is deprecated. Now you should use `sass` or downgrade your node version to build

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril The code was not write by myself, so I can't change the dependency. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the nexus proxy repository to another mirror url, and the problem  was gone. Thanks everyone for trying to deal the problem!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).